# Handle gems and their versions for one file scripts

Tags: ruby, version-control, rubygems

I have a directory full of scripts mostly written in ruby. Most of them have only `require` calls, so after some time it is not always clear which gem provides the file or if gem changes — the script can become incompatible.

I can add `gem` calls specifying versions, but if combined with `require` calls will look excessive for small scripts.

Is there something like inline bundler without lock file, so only specifying gem versions, handling version resolution, automatic requiring and everything inline in ruby script?

Answer (score 0):

If it 'looks excessive' then perhaps it is? This is purely subjective.

Using `gem 'gem_name', 'version.number.s'` is the way to do so, as I imagine you are doing from your words.

Once you get to the point where you need more than one file, because the organization demands it, do so.  Don't fight something that is naturally occurring without a reason.

For example, for a test that only runs when called directly in this "small script" for whatever measurement of small qualifies as that limitation...

```
def hello(name_ = 'World', name: name_)
  "Hello #{name}"
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  gem 'minitest', '5.7.0'
  require 'minitest/autorun'

  describe hello do
    it 'must return "Hello World:"' do
      assert_equal hello, 'Hello World!'
    end
  end
end
```

Having the gem specified there as is, does not require a `Gemfile.lock` (it isn't a gem, and doesn't include or have a `Gemfile`) only requires that I have that gem available / installed.

It will complain if that gem is not available.